# iterate through the links of a website recursively

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and I wrote a function that should iterate through all the links of a website recursively and get me the links at the end with '.csv' or '.pdf' that contain the word 'XYZ' in the link. Here is what I wrote but it's returning me nothing. What am I doing wrong?

```py
def parse(self, response):
    for each in response.xpath('//a/@href').getall():
        if each.endswith(".csv") or each.endswith(".pdf") and "XYZ" in each:
            mylist.append(each)
        yield response.follow(each, self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide an example of the url you're working with because it helps detect if the issues are `xpath` related or something else, more quickly.

My guess is the following:

1. You likely want to add 4 spaces to yield so it's within the `if` statement, given you only want those with `.csv` or `.pdf`.
2. your `xpath` is not returning the links so nothing is being followed.

Comment: I think you should give this as a comment to the question and not an answer since you are seeking for clarification to the question

Comment: @msenior_ I agree - however I did not have 50 reps to comment at the time. Although, if my guesses are right then it suffices as an answe.r